# how to print out a multiplication table, from 1x1 to 12x12 in perl

Tags: perl

I need to print a multiplication table.. that should look like 12X12 table.

here is the script that I tried

```
@array=(1..10);
$count=1;
while($count<11)
{
    foreach $mul (@array)
    {
        $multiply=$count*$mul;
        push(@multifinal,$multiply);
    }
    print"@multifinal\n";
    @multifinal =() ;
    $count++;
}
```

This what I'm getting as an output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12

2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24

3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30 33 36

4 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40 44 48

5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50 55 60

6 12 18 24 30 36 42 48 54 60 66 72

7 14 21 28 35 42 49 56 63 70 77 84

8 16 24 32 40 48 56 64 72 80 88 96

9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81 90 99 108

10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100 110 120

11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 99 110 121 132

12 24 36 48 60 72 84 96 108 120 132 144
```

I don't know how to assign it with table's row and column.. can you pls help to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest change would be to add some basic formatting to your print:

```
printf "%3d "x12 ."\n", @multifinal;
```

Which makes 12 slots, each 3 digits wide plus a space, to print the array into.

And the entire program could look like this if you weren't interested in the arrays:

```
for my $count (1..12) { 
   printf "%3d "x12 ."\n", map( $count * $_, 1..12 ) 
}
```

If you are interested in the arrays, those can be generated as well:

```
my $max=12;
my @table; 
for my $row (1..$max) { 
  push @table, [ map( $row * $_, 1..$max ) ];
}
print $table[11][11],"\n"; # 0 based indexes
```

Take a look at the [documentation for `map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) to better understand how the rows are being populated.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is the perl module Text::Table

http://use.perl.org/use.perl.org/_Ovid/journal/36762.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@ar = (1..12);
for $s(@ar){
printf "%s\t",$s * $_,foreach (@ar); 
print "\n";
}
```

Output

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12 
2   4   6   8  10  12  14  16  18  20  22  24 
3   6   9  12  15  18  21  24  27  30  33  36 
4   8  12  16  20  24  28  32  36  40  44  48 
5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50  55  60 
6  12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54  60  66  72 
7  14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  70  77  84 
8  16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72  80  88  96 
9  18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81  90  99 108 
10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90 100 110 120 
11  22  33  44  55  66  77  88  99 110 121 132 
12  24  36  48  60  72  84  96 108 120 132 144
```

Answer (score 0):

Use two 'for' loops and multiple as you go.

This works nicely and it's easy to read:

```
for my $i (1 .. 12) {

  #print a new line for each row with 12 rows total
  print "\n";

  #print out the numbers per row in multiples of $i * $j
  for my $j (1 .. 12) {

    #%4d will format output nice and even
    printf ("%4d ", $j*$i);

  }

}

print "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a standard one-liner approach followed by one that uses [`Perl6::Form`](https://www.metacpan.org/pod/Perl6::Form):

```
perl -e 'for my $n (1..12) {printf "%3d "x12 ."\n" , map{ $n * $_ } 1..12 }'

perl -MPerl6::Form -e 'for my $n (1..12){print form "{<<}"x12, map{ $n * $_ } 1..12 }'
```

---

**About the `Perl6::Form` Module**

Except for a dependency on [`Perl6::Export`](https://www.metacpan.org/pod/Perl6::Export), which needs a very small number of atypical modules, [`Perl6::Form`](https://www.metacpan.org/pod/Perl6::Form) is quite lightweight.  In fact the `Perl6::Export` "`is export`" trait is only used for a handful of subroutines. It'd be nice to have Perl ship with a shiny built in Perl6 style `form` command to complement the traditional `format` command but, until then, [`Perl6::Export`](https://www.metacpan.org/pod/Perl6::Export) fits the bill.